# It is possible to change the ion-title size inside ion-navbar?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

```
<ion-navbar color="primary">
  <ion-title>Atualizado em: {{ultimaAtualizacao |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

I want to change the text size of the ion-title, I have already tried using css, but it does not change.

Answer (score 7):

1. If you want to change it **for every page of the app**, you can use the sass variables. You'd need to add the following in your `variables.scss` file:

   ```
   $toolbar-ios-title-font-size: 1.7rem;
   $toolbar-md-title-font-size: 2rem;
   $toolbar-wp-title-font-size: 1.5rem;
   ```

   Those are the defaults, so you can set the values that you want there.
2. If you want to change in **only in one page**, you shouldn't use the sass variables. Instead, use a simple css rule in that page's scss file:

   ```
   your-page {

     toolbar-title toolbar-title-ios { 
       font-size: 1.7rem;
     }

     toolbar-title toolbar-title-md { 
       font-size: 2rem;
     }

     toolbar-title toolbar-title-wp { 
       font-size: 1.5rem;
     }

   }
   ```

---

EDIT:

If using the css rules don't work, it may be an issue related to the specificity of those rules. You can try by wrapping the styles of the page like this:

```
.ios, .md, .wp {

  your-page {

    // Put your css rules here!

  }

}
```

By doing that, you can improve the specificity of your custom css rules, and overwrite Ionic's css rules.

Comment: should there be 3 `toolbar-title toolbar-title-ios` in the css?

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing that out @johnny5. Each rule suppose to target a different platform (I've edited that mistake in the answer).

Comment: @sebaferras thank I would of fixed it myself, but I wasn't sure of the css classes,  do you happen to know of a page where I can find all of the Ionic sass variables?

Comment: Of course! **[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)** you can find all the sass variables @johnny5

Answer (score 3):

### IONIC 3:

Put this voice on your `scss` page:

```
.toolbar-title-md {
    font-size: 1.5rem !important; // Default should be 2.0rem
}
```

Comment: This will only change the ion title on android.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official API docs, it is possible to override SASS variables.
[Check it out...](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Title/#sass-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You access the title with:

```css
ion-toolbar .toolbar-title{
  font-size: 100%;
}
```